# How to use inbuilt call recording functionality in Android?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, phone-call, call-recording, oneplusone

Samsung and one plus mobiles are providing default call recording functionality in android 9 and 10. Is there any way to use that inbuilt call recording feature in my android application? I tried with lot of ways. But I'm unable to record a call. Please tell me how to use inbuild OS call recording functionality.